# How to input 2d list in function?

Tags: python

I want function maxmintuple(m), that takes m, a 2D list returns a tuple with the min value and max value in the corresponding brackets. eg:

```
maxmintuple ([[3,5],[6,8]])

(3,8)
```

This is how I call it:

maxmintuple([1,5],[2,8])

and it returns this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    maxmintuple([1,5],[2,8])
TypeError: maxmintuple() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Here's what I have, but it keeps saying

maxmintuple() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Here's what I did:

```
def maxmintuple(m):

    max1 = m[O][O]
    min1 = m[O][O]

    for zero in m:
        for one in zero:
            if one > max1:
                max1 = one 
            if one < min1:
                min1 = one 

    return (min1,max1)
```

Comment: There's no error in the code you posted (except using the letter `O` instead of the number `0`)

Comment: Can you explain what is the exact issue here or provide the current output please

Comment: When I copy/paste your code I get a different error: `NameError: name 'O' is not defined`. This is because you have the letter OH when I think you mean the number ZERO: https://replit.com/@codeguru/EquatorialRegalConstants#main.py

Comment: You need to call your function like `maxmintuple([[3, 5], [6, 8]])` but you're calling it like `maxmintuple([3, 5], [6, 8])` instead (in code you didn't include as part of your question).

Comment: @Samwise Interestingly, the first line of code in the post is correct.

Comment: Yes, but that's not their actual code, it's probably the prompt that was part of the assignment since it also includes the desired output (and they transcribed it without the enclosing `[]`s in their actual code).

Comment: I call it like this: maxmintuple([1,5],[2,8])

Comment: @COCO2122 You are missing a some brackets. Double check your code with what your assignment says.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to change your function to:

```py
def maxmintuple(m):

    min1 = min(m[0])
    max1 = max(m[1])

    return (min1,max1)
```

Let's apply it with your 2D list example:

```py
maxmintuple([[3,5],[6,8]])
```

**Output**

```py
(3, 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function wrong. you need to call like below

`maxmintuple([[1,5],[2,8]])`